# How to initialize a character and scan a string in the initialized character?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[2] ;

    printf("Enter a string of 2 characters\n");

    scanf("%s", c);
    printf("%s \n",c);
}
```

I have no idea why the above doesnt work.
Please enlighten me...

Comment: I guess this must be a really easy question, but i did struggle with it for quite some time and Im a beginner in programming

Comment: In the future when asking questions about something that "doesn't work", it might be a good idea *how* it doesn't work. For example, for some example input, what is the expected and actual output? does the program crash? Do you get build errors?

Comment: Take a look at the tag-wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/info

Answer (score 1):

Do this `char c[3]` because after the string of 2 characters , you have to assign the space for `\0` also.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that a string of two characters actually contains *three* characters: The two characters of the string and a special string-terminator character (`'\0'`).

If you give two characters as input, the `scanf` call will write three characters (including the string terminator) to the array `c`, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As long as you have undefined behavior in your program, anything could happen, including the calling of [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c[3] = {0};//+1 for '\0'(EOS)

    printf("Enter a string of 2 characters\n");

    scanf("%2c", c);//or scanf("%2s", c);//?
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```